# Why do I get a different answer by using substitution and integral by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Why do I get a different answer by using substitution and integral by parts for this integral?

$$\int \dfrac{2x}{(x-5)^2} dx$$

Substitution:

let $u=x-5$. $du = dx, x = u+5$

$$=\int\dfrac{2(u+5)}{u^2} du = 2u^{-1}+10u^{-2} du = 2 \ln{|u|}-\dfrac{10}{u} + C = 2 \ln{|x-5|}-\dfrac{10}{x-5}+C$$

Integral by parts:

$u = 2x, dv = \dfrac{1}{(x-5)^2}$

$du = 2 dx, v = -\dfrac{1}{x-5}$

$$=-2x\dfrac{1}{x-5} +\int{\dfrac{2}{x-5} dx} = 2 \ln{|x-5|}-\dfrac{2x}{x-5}+C$$

Comment: It's quite hard to read. Try mathjax which is the site standard. It's not hard once you get the hang of it.

Comment: $$\frac{2x}{x-5}=\frac{2x-10+10}{x-5}=2+\frac{10}{x-5}\\~\\$$

Hence, they only differ by a constant and are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't think about to put -10 and +10. By the way, this is my first time to ask question, i will learn to use mathjax as quick as i can.

Comment: @learner You should make that an answer.

Comment: "this is my first time to ask question, i will learn to use mathjax as quick as i can." I am very glad to here that from a first time user... Keep goint.. +1 for your question...

Comment: @Max, for starters, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a basic mathjax tutorial.

Comment: Thanks everyone again, all of you are really nice!